# Accidentally beat sugar and butter together

Tags: cake

I was doing a pound cake and instead of gradually adding the sugar to the butter, I mixed both together. I continued with the recipe because I was too afraid of telling my mom. Will my cake come out good? Or it does not affect anything?

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't make any difference.

Here are some recipes that don't mention adding the sugar bit by bit:

- [Vanilla Pound Cake](https://www.marthastewart.com/337155/vanilla-pound-cake)
- [Traditional Pound Cake](https://thestayathomechef.com/traditional-pound-cake-recipe/)
- [Pound Cake](https://www.bettycrocker.com/recipes/pound-cake/0571fe76-c8d7-4e1b-b75e-b4a3fcac5b8e)

If you beat the butter and sugar to a fluffy consistency everything should be all right.

(As far as I know) The worst that could happen is that your pound cake will be slightly denser than usual.